# What is the wrong with called object in Java code?

Tags: java, oop, netbeans

I'm creating a menu using Java code and when I create a new object in the main class it shows me these two errors:

> variable admin has not been initialized

and

> incompatible string cannot convert to double.

Here is the Admin class:

```
public class Admin extends User {
    private String officNo;
    private String positon;

    public Admin(String username, String pass, String officeNo, String postion) {
        super(username, pass);
    }

    public void addProduct(Product p) {
        Store.products.add(p);
    }
}
```

The product class:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private String ID;
    private double price;
    private String seller;

    public Product(String name, String id, double price, String sell) {
    }
}
```

The main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Admin admin;

    Scanner inter = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to our Online Store\n\n if you are an admin enter 1 if user enter 2");
    int sw1 = inter.nextInt();
    switch(sw1) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("choose one of the option below: \n"
                 + "(1) add a new product to the store\n" +
                   "(2) delete one of the products\n" +
                   "(3) update one of the product attributes\n" +
                   "(4) search if a certain product exits using its ID\n" +
                   "(5) show the list of products\n"+
                   "(6) exit" );

         int sw2 = inter.nextInt();
         switch(sw2) {
             case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter product name: " );
                String name=inter.next();
                System.out.println("Enter product ID: " );
                String id=inter.next();
                System.out.println("Enter product price: " );
                String price=inter.next();
                System.out.println("Enter product seller: " );
                String seller=inter.next();

               admin.addProduct(new Product(name,id,price,seller);
                break;
```

The error comes in this line:

```
admin.addProduct(new Product(name,id,price,seller);
```

Please, can any one help?

Comment: The `price` parameter is a `double`, you can't just throw a `String` at it.  You need to parse the string into a double (and hopefully add something to handle the exception for when somebody gives you bad input).

Comment: the error message is pretty clear. Initialize `admin` variable and use `double` for price

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized the variable `admin`. At a minimum, you need to initialize it like this:

```
Admin admin = null; // or some other initial value
```

In your case though you would need to actually initialize it with a non-null value or you will get a `NullPointerException` on the line you highlighted.

```
Admin admin = new Admin();
```

Additionally, you are reading the price in as a string and then passing it to the `Product` constructor which is expecting a double. You will need to convert the string to a double first and then pass it in the constructor.

Comment: There's more errors than that. If it's only one error, it's very rare.

Comment: I added a bit about the string to double issue. There are definitely a number of issues with this code.

Comment: if I create new object it shows me errors with arguments

Comment: ... look at the last paragraph of this answer.